# openvpn-auth-ldap: How to require multiple group membership

Tags: openvpn

I've been able to successfully authenticate with ldap, using a single group using the following config...

```
<Group>
  BaseDN          "OU=Groups,OU=Users,OU=AD,DC=ad,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
  SearchFilter    "(CN=VPN Users)"
  MemberAttribute member
</Group>
```

I'm now attempting to setup an admin specific openvpn instance which will require membership in the "Admins" group, in addition to the "VPN Users" group. However I haven't been able to find the correct syntax to do this.

This is what I've tried...

```
<Group>
  BaseDN          "OU=Groups,OU=Users,OU=AD,DC=ad,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
  SearchFilter    "(&(CN=VPN Users)(CN=Admins))"
  MemberAttribute member
</Group>
```

This failed authentication.

Then I tried including 2 group sections, like this...

```
<Group>
  BaseDN          "OU=Groups,OU=Users,OU=AD,DC=ad,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
  SearchFilter    "(CN=VPN Users)"
  MemberAttribute member
</Group>
<Group>
  BaseDN          "OU=Groups,OU=Users,OU=AD,DC=ad,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
  SearchFilter    "(CN=Admins)"
  MemberAttribute member
</Group>
```

In this case it authenticated if the user was a member of either of the groups. It didn't require membership in both.

I could potentially just create another group, but that then becomes extra hassle to manage. If possible I would really like to be able to work with the groups we already have.